# How to replace x-axes with our own timestamp data from API in Highcharts using highstocks

Tags: javascript, highcharts, timestamp

This is my first time using highcharts. I kinda confused because last time I used Chart.js. I want my chart can show data per month, week, year, and day. And I want it to have datepicker. So I try to search some example. And finally I make my own. But there is not option to show my data per week and day. And the x-axes of the graph are not from my own data. How can I make my x-axes to use my own timestamp API data? And how to change the option to show data per day,week,and month?

This is my code : https://jsfiddle.net/estri012/y1usoxd7/6/

Anyone please help me. I am a newbie programmer and still have lot of problem with programming. But this is for my school task. So I need to finish it. Thankyou!

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>

Highcharts.getJSON('https://gmlews.com/api/data', function (data) {
console.log(data);
var accelero_x = [], timestamp = [];
      for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        accelero_x.push(data[i].accelero_x);
        timestamp.push(data[i].timestamp);
     }
      console.log(accelero_x);
      console.log(timestamp); 
// Create the chart
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Accelero X'
    },


    series: [{
        name: 'Accelero X',
        data: accelero_x,
        type: 'spline',
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
        }
    }]
 });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind using highchart stockchart is it uses x-axis label as timestamp.

Solution to "How can I make my x-axes to use my own timestamp API data? " should be converting data[i].timestamp by parsing to real timestamp and create nested array of 'accelero_x' and pass that array to series data.

```
Highcharts.getJSON('https://gmlews.com/api/data', function (data) {
console.log(data);
var accelero_x = [], timestamp = [];
      for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
      //modification start -----
      let inArr = [];
      let trimDate = data[i].timestamp.split('T')[0]; // here we have many ways to extract only the date correctly
      inArr.push(Date.parse(trimDate));
      inArr.push(data[i].accelero_x);
        accelero_x.push(inArr);
      //modification end -----
        timestamp.push(data[i].timestamp);
     }
      console.log(accelero_x);
      console.log(timestamp); 
// Create the chart
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Accelero X'
    },


    series: [{
        name: 'Accelero X',
        data: accelero_x,
        type: 'spline',
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
        }
    }]
 });
 });
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jinny/jrhz3ty7/20/

Comment: May be you have to put some more effort to create custom filter where you can filter and group sort api data into week and month and initialize same graph with filtered data make sure you maintain parsing date to timestamp everytime

Comment: how if i don't use highstock? just highchart. Is it possible to have datepicker too? Can you give me example

Comment: I don't have an example ready because even for me highchart is new, but for time being you can see into https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=20852

Comment: meanwhile I am also looking for the solution but i think is possible to add datepicker

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jinny/jrhz3ty7/74/ in this solution I added date range to normal chart as you asked before

Comment: I have a problem, on the chart the last three data shown 18 March, but actually in my API it is 19 March. Why this is happen? The other data is fine. Just those data which not showing the right date

Comment: I have to further add the logic to split data[index].timestamp at 'T' to extract only the date part and parse in order to show correct date on x-axis. I don't know exact reason why iI have to do but may be this is what you need that I have shared in solution. https://jsfiddle.net/jinny/jrhz3ty7/90/

Comment: Oh i know! On the chart, it shows UTC timezone, meanwhile in my API is local timezone. So i have to convert  or make the UTC timezone disable on the chart

Answer (score 0):

- Here is an API options how to set the range selections options: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector.buttons
- Your second part of the question - Highcharts requires data in the following formats:

  - array of values - like: `[10,20,30,40]` - Highcharts reads it as an array of y values and set default x values - `1, 2, 3, 4`
  - array of arrays - like: `[[3, 24], [5, 42], [8,33]]` - where first value in the array is an x and the second one is the y - `[x, y]`
  - array of objects - like: `[{x: 3, y: 24}, {x: 5, y: 42}]` - here is quite obvious

The xAxis could be a datatime type, where x value is a value in milliseconds format, that's mean you will need to convert your data into the milisecond value to set it, like here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w9hznsey/